# How to get weather data from site?

Tags: python, html, lxml

I'm not able to get the Dew_Point and Wind Data from the site https://weather.gc.ca/city/pages/ab-52_metric_e.html

import requests
from lxml import html

```
        # Get the html page
        resp=requests.get("https://weather.gc.ca/city/pages/ab-52_metric_e.html")
        # Build html tree
        html_tree=html.fromstring(resp.text)

        #Dew_point=html_tree.xpath("//dd[@class='mrgn-bttm-0 wxo-metric-hide'][(parent::dl[@class='dl-horizontal wxo-conds-col2'])]//text()")[1].replace("Â", "")
        # Print Dew_point
        #print(f"Dew_point in {city_name} is {Dew_point}")  

        #Wind=html_tree.xpath("//dd[@class='longContent mrgn-bttm-0 wxo-metric-hide'][(parent::dl[@class='dl-horizontal wxo-conds-col2'])]//text()")[0].replace("Â", "")
        # Print Wind
        #print(f"Wind in {city_name} is {Wind}")
```

Data should be in the following format:
Dew point:-2.3°C
Wind: NE 9 km/h

The direction for wind may change.

I'm not sure how to parse the following HTML code, thanks again for the help!

```
<dt>Temperature:</dt>
<dd class="mrgn-bttm-0 wxo-metric-hide">13.2°<abbr title="Celsius">C</abbr>
</dd>
<dd class="mrgn-bttm-0 wxo-imperial-hide wxo-city-hidden">55.8°
                    <abbr title="Fahrenheit">F</abbr>
</dd>
<dt>Dew point:</dt>
<dd class="mrgn-bttm-0 wxo-metric-hide">-2.3°<abbr title="Celsius">C</abbr>
</dd>
<dd class="mrgn-bttm-0 wxo-imperial-hide wxo-city-hidden">27.9°<abbr title="Fahrenheit">F</abbr>
</dd>
<dt>Humidity:</dt>
<dd class="mrgn-bttm-0">34%</dd>
</dl></div>
<div class="col-sm-4"><dl class="dl-horizontal wxo-conds-col3">
<dt>Wind:</dt>
<dd class="longContent mrgn-bttm-0 wxo-metric-hide">
<abbr title="Northeast">NE</abbr> 9 <abbr title="kilometres per hour">km/h</abbr>
</dd>
<dd class="longContent mrgn-bttm-0 wxo-imperial-hide wxo-city-hidden">
<abbr title="Northeast">NE</abbr> 6 <abbr title="miles per hour">mph</abbr>
</dd>
<dt>Visibility:</dt>
<dd class="mrgn-bttm-0 wxo-metric-hide">48 <abbr title="kilometres">km</abbr>
</dd>
<dd class="mrgn-bttm-0 wxo-imperial-hide wxo-city-hidden">30 miles</dd>
</dl></div>
```

Comment: "I'm not sure how to parse the following HTML code, thanks again for the help!" If you mean "How do I parse the following HTML code?", then **ask that** - we want clear, [specific](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236) questions here, [not thanks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288160/no-thanks-damn-it), because this is **not a discussion forum**. If you do have some idea but it went wrong, then either [try to locate](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) a problem and show a [mre], or else ask specifically about *how to do that part*.

Comment: Also: assuming that you have [already determined](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) that the right way to approach the problem is to download the HTML and parse it (as opposed to, say, looking for an API); you already have working code that gives you that HTML; and the *problem* is how to parse the HTML, then *ask a question about parsing the HTML*. It does not help to show us how you got the HTML, because that doesn't change how to parse it; that code is irrelevant to the question, and the title is actively misleading. Please read [ask].

Comment: I can see  that you have some commented-out code that looks like it's intended to parse the HTML. **What happens** when you try using that? **How is that different** from what is supposed to happen? Please actually describe a concrete problem.

Comment: Hi, will do that and check over the FAQ for how to ask questions, wasn't aware of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bs4's [BeautifulSoup](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-work-with-web-data-using-requests-and-beautiful-soup-with-python-3#stepping-through-a-page-with-beautiful-soup) is often used to parse html and extract data. In your case, it can be utilized in several ways; first parse and get the html tree [`soup`] with

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

resp = requests.get("https://weather.gc.ca/city/pages/ab-52_metric_e.html")
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.content, "html.parser")
```

[I like using the [`select`](https://www.codespeedy.com/find-elements-by-css-selector-in-beautifulsoup/) function, and you can consult [this reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) if you're confused by any of the selectors.]

---

Now, if you want the current weather, then

```py
selector = '#mainContent details.visible-xs dt+dd'
for s in soup.select(selector):
    print(s.find_previous_sibling().text.strip(), s.text.strip(), end=' ')
```

will output

```
Wind: NE 8 km/h Temperature: 18.2°C Pressure: 101.9 kPa Dew point: -8.1°C Visibility: 24 km Humidity: 16% Date: 8:00 PM MDT Wednesday 19 October 2022 Observed at: Calgary Int'l Airport
```

but you also commented about wanting the Condition and Tendency, and you *could* get the Condition simply with

```py
print(f"Condition: {soup.select_one('details.visible-xs div>img+p')}")
```

but Tendency is actually in a different section which is not visible. You could change `selector` to `'#mainContent section:first-of-type dt+dd'` or even to just `'dt+dd'` and run `for s in soup.select(selector)....` again, but you will several repeated values and unwanted data, so we probably need a more structured approach.

---

---

So I defined a function that will take a section of the tree and return *one* value per condition -

```py
def getWeatherData(sectionSoup, pKeys='all', cwcSelector='dt+dd', pEnd=' '):
    wc = []
    for s in sectionSoup.select(cwcSelector):
        wcName = s.find_previous_sibling().text.strip()
        wcVal = s.text.strip()

        vis = 'hidden' if s.find_parent(class_='hidden-xs') else 'visible'
        wc.append((wcName, wcVal, vis)) 

    wcs = sorted(wc, key=lambda c: c[2], reverse=True) # visible first
    if pKeys == 'all' or type(pKeys) != list: 
      pKeys = list(set([c[0] for c in wc]))
      allKeys = True
    else: allKeys = False

    forOp = []
    for k in pKeys:
      kvp = [c for c in wcs if c[0].replace(':','')==k.replace(':','')]
      if kvp == []:
          # continue # if you want to skip
          if pEnd is None or type(pEnd) == str: 
              print(f'! UNAVAILABLE : "{k}" !', end=pEnd)
      else: 
          if allKeys: k = k.replace(':', '') # remove if you want to preserve originial text
          forOp.append((k, kvp[0][1]))
          if pEnd is None or type(pEnd) == str: 
              print(kvp[0][0], kvp[0][1], end=pEnd) 
      
    print()
    return dict(forOp)
    
    # if you want all the values, including repeats:
    # return {'filtered': forOp, 'unfiltered': wc}
```

Now you can define which parts of the data you want, and what order you want it in:

```py
toPrint = [
    'Condition', 'Pressure', 'Tendency', 'Temperature', 
    'Dew point', 'Humidity', 'Wind', 'Visibility'
] # the parts you mentioned wanting

cwc = getWeatherData(soup.select_one('#mainContent section'), toPrint)
print(f'\n##############\nAs Dictionary:\n{cwc}')
```

and that will output

```markdown
Condition: Partly Cloudy Pressure: 101.3 kPa Tendency: Rising Temperature: 8.9°C Dew point: -0.3°C Humidity: 52% Wind: N 43  gust 54 km/h Visibility: 24 km 

##############
As Dictionary:
{'Condition': 'Partly Cloudy', 'Pressure': '101.3 kPa', 'Tendency': 'Rising', 'Temperature': '8.9°C', 'Dew point': '-0.3°C', 'Humidity': '52%', 'Wind': 'N 43  gust 54 km/h', 'Visibility': '24 km'}
```

[Send `pEnd='\n'` if you want each value printed on a separate line, or `pEnd=False` if you don't want to print at all; and send `pKeys='all'` (instead of `toPrint`) if you want to see all available data.]

---

---

If you wanted, you could also see all collapsible sections (hidden and visible) with

```py
wcSects = [s.find_parent('details') for s in soup.select('details dd+dt')]

for s in list(set(wcSects)):
  print('\n#######', end=' ')  
  h2 = s.select_one('summary h2')
  print((h2 if h2 else s.summary).text.strip(), '#######')
  getWeatherData(s, 'all', pEnd=' | ')
```

Comment: Thanks, this is working very nicely, is it possible to use the text as dictionary key, and the readings as the dictonary value like so ?  mydict = {"Pressure": "101.0 kPa","Condition": "Mostly Cloudy"...}
mylist = ["Pressure: 101.0 kPa, "Condition: Mostly Cloudy"...] I know I haven't asked this initially, either list or dictonary like above would work nicely for the next section needing this result.

Comment: @laisp-CAD please see the edited function and output

Comment: @Drifter95, thank you for the prompt response, this is what I am looking for, appreciate your help!

Comment: @Drifter95 I do have another similiar post for web scrapping that I will need help on... Soon I will have to ask if bs4 package and be converted or added in IronPython2....it's possible this environment may change...which I'm also not familiar with.

Comment: @laisp-CAD I'm not particularly familiar with IronPython myself, but bs4 is a purely python library so it *should* be unproblematic. good luck!

Comment: @Drifter95 Thanks, your other solution worked as well, though I end up asking for a bit extra on top hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 1):

The best approach is to use BeautifulSoup to parse the page.

This is what you want:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

resp = requests.get("https://weather.gc.ca/city/pages/ab-52_metric_e.html").content

soup = BeautifulSoup(resp, "html.parser")

all_dt = soup.find_all("dt")

#if you want more metrics, just add it to the list
metrics = ["Dew point:","Wind:","Pressure:","Condition:","Tendency:","Temperature:", "Humidity:", "Visibility:"]

data = {}

for metric in metrics:
  data[metric] = []

for elem in all_dt:
  if elem.text in metrics:
    value = elem.next_sibling.next_sibling
    data[elem.text].append(value.text.strip("\n") if  value != None else "No Data")

print(data)
```

Comment: Hi, above code does work, would like to access the following sibling elements,      
Condition: Partly Cloudy
Pressure: 102.0 kPa
Tendency: Falling
Temperature: 23.3°C
Dew point: -5.7°C
Humidity: 14%
Wind: S 10 km/h
Visibility:
24 km

Comment: I will edit the answer with a more flexible code. If it resolver your question, please accept it.

Comment: {'Dew point:': ['-1.9°C', '-1.9°C', '-1.9°C'], 'Wind:': ['N 27  gust 39 km/h', 'N 27  gust 39 km/h', 'N 27  gust 39 km/h'], 'Pressure:': ['101.0 kPa', '101.0 kPa', '101.0 kPa'], 'Condition:': ['Mostly Cloudy', 'Mostly Cloudy'], 'Tendency:': ['Falling', 'Falling'], 'Temperature:': ['15.9°C', '15.9°C', '15.9°C'], 'Humidity:': ['29%', '29%', '29%'], 'Visibility:': ['19 km', '19 km', '19 km']} Hi this does work, just the items appear 3 times, I believe this is because the text does appear 3 times as td when viewed as inspecting the source element.